# Remove username and password from config files

Tags: .net, github, configuration-files

I am trying to remove userid and password from the configuration files after the user checks in the code. I am using Github as my source control.

I dont want to use gitignore to remove the complete configuration file as I need 
them in my source control repo.

I have tried and read about the roslyn to edit ( there was no luck).

What are the other alternatives?

Comment: Roslyn has nothing to do with config files.

Comment: @SLaks How can this be achieved?

Comment: Typically, by moving credentials out of config files, and instead using an out-of-band source like environment variables or deployment scripts.